# Avoid visual studio from adding underscores to the ID fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Say I Have a model named Project with properties StartDate,EndDate etc.If I have a editor view that accepts the model then the HTML generated has ids as StartDate,EndDate
however if I have a ProjectViewmodel that is being passed to the editor view, one that contains Project model then the editor generates HTML with tags as Project_StartDate.is there a way to avoid the underscores. Its annoying because say you have a jquery accessing a specific ID ,and you changed the model of the view, you need to remember to change the jquery too

Answer (score 1):

Override it with your own ID

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Project.StartDate, new { id = "StartDate" })
```

This will produce an input with `id="StartDate"`

Comment: Beat me by 20 seconds!...+1 anyway.

Comment: :-) That happens to me all the time!

Comment: however I am using @Html.EditoForModel(Model.Project)

Comment: So don't use `EditorForModel`, instead use `EditorFor` and create an Editor Template that represents your Project view model. You have to choose between control over your objects or letting the framework handle it.